# Stop execution of any method without closing the application

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application which runs on a single thread, but does a lot of things (executing methods in a loop to automate webbrowser app).

I am a beginner, so the code is probably poorly organized, but I need to add a following feature to the program - a STOP button.

What it needs to do is simply send a 'return;' to any method that is or would be executed next, so that the program returns to a ready-and-waiting stage (i.e. I don't loose user provided data, but no other iteration of any loop is carried out etc.).

Any idea?

I tried `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();` but this actually kills the whole application. Any idea for a good generic solution?

Cheers!

Comment: Long-running methods should not execute on the UI thread.

Comment: Funny you mention threads because you will most likely want to use another thread.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the thread in its own process, and if you need to stop it, stop the process.

Comment: are you using c# or java?

Comment: I am using c# and I would be glad to use another thread - it's just that I don't know how:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all if you are just using one thread with your application. Then you cant send cancelTokens to your methods. However if you start using Tasks, which are threads then you can provide yourself the ability to use cancelTokens on your methods.

Here is a very simple example I wrote of using a cancelToken in a program that has threads.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool cancelToken = false;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            while (!cancelToken)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running....");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }));

        t.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        cancelToken = true;
        t.Join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code snippet. I tried something of that sort, however I have quickly run into an exception. I don't know how to implement practically. My program is structured in a way that a start button triggers a series of tens of method - and a short while after pressing start I got an error that a method was called from a different thread or something... Let me fetch it in a second

Comment: `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'kryptonPanel1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` that is the message

Comment: @Bartosz So you are trying to access something in the KryptonPanel from a thread other than the one that created the KryptonPanel object. Without seeing your code I can just provide you with a reference on how to make a thread safe call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

If you provide me with your code I will be able to assist you better.

Comment: @Bartosz Are you using windows forms or wpf?

Comment: @Bartosz Awesome then the link I gave you should work perfectly for your needs. As a side note cross thread call in WPF are a lot easier because their message pump is a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single-threaded GUI program, then you can't take any user commands while it's processing something.  If you do as others have suggested, and dump the processing into a worker thread, then you can send an interrupt signal to that thread to stop it.